# How to disable events when runtime Delphi VCL Style changes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I want to use VCL Style's in my application.
I have some code in events OnShow, OnResize...

When changing styles triggered other form events.(FormShow, FormResize)

How to disable events when on change style.

For change style i use code:

```
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(cbStyles.Items[cbStyles.ItemIndex], True);
```

Sample Code:

```
procedure TForm1.AddLog(AMsg: String);
begin
  if cbEnableLog.Checked
  then  Memo1.Lines.Append(AMsg);
end;

procedure TForm1.bChangeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(cbStyles.Items[cbStyles.ItemIndex],True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddLog('FormResize');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddLog('FormShow');
end;
```

[image: Called events.]

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this. You'll have to code it up yourself. Have all of your events bail out early by testing a boolean that you set.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a boolean variable, f.ex. `InStyleChange: boolean;`. Set it `True` before you call `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle()` and reset to `False` right after.

In all event handlers where you want to bypass the event write code like:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if InStyleChange then exit;
  AddLog('FormResize');
end;
```

Comment: When i use like this code. its running few times. Then raises exception in my application.

Comment: @zgn, what type of exception? If you log before and after `TrySetStyle`, are there events coming later?

Comment: @zgn The change suggested in this answer cannot result in the behaviour you describe. Don't expect us to debug what we can't see. It's time for you to learn to debug your own code.

Comment: @LU-RD Exception is : Error creating windows device context. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My question is clear. Please be patient. I'm looking for a real solution. ok?

Comment: With the code you have shown for the two event handlers, it is impossible that the modification I suggested would be the reason for the exception. Show the **real and complete code** of the event handler that raises the exception.